# Using Team Foundation Server for iOS applications

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, tfs

In my organisation we are using Team foundation server for source control. Is it possible to use Team foundation server with Xcode?

Comment: We had tried a lot but ended up with SVN.

Comment: There are good examples all over the internet for this. You can look at Xamerin or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/19/building-ios-apps-in-tfs.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct linkup between your XCode (Mac) and TFS (Microsoft), Both are reverse technology, But you can go through Git.

And also you can go with [Eclipse and manage your repository](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/01/28/how-to-use-tfs-on-a-mac.aspx)y.

Answer (score 2):

Team Foundation Server 2013 and Visual Studio Online have great support for Git. This automatically means that you can use TFS with all developer environments that support Git or from the command line.

[Share your Xcode projects](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/share-your-xcode-projects-vs.aspx) explains how you can enable Git support for use with XCode.

When you have your code in TFS, there is no problem in using the Agile project management tooling. Build is another story. You can get this working by using a cross platform build tool like Jenkins or by creating manual scripts that you integrate with a TFS build.

Answer (score 0):

use git-tf or Smart-SVN for version control